# Why does the links and hover effects work on my computer but no one elses?

Tags: html, css

So the site is [www.KBduct.com](http://www.kbduct.com). I was given the assignment to create a new red button on the homepage for Explosion Isolation valves. I had simply copied the coding used to create the other buttons such as 'Ducting layout Planner' and changed the background color. The buttons work fine on my computer but for everyone else, it seems that they are unable to click on the buttons. The hovering effect I added doesn't work as well.

I've inspected all elements and found that the CSS and html coding looks to be just fine. I've tested it out on Firefox, Internet explorer, and chrome on my computer. Absolutely no problems but this isn't the case for everyone else. I believe that for some odd reason the buttons aren't being recognized as linked elements but simply static images instead. I've tried adding the anchor tag to the div instead but that just makes the box around the text disappear completely.

At this point I'm perplexed and need to know why this is happening.

CODE:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<div class="catalog">



            <a href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/ducting-components-catalog-order/"><p>DOWNLOAD CATALOG <img src="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/img/download_icon.png"></p></a>



</div>



<div class="catalog">



            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_tbdgGVGrU&feature=youtu.be" target="_blank"><p>CLAMP TOGETHER VIDEO </p></a>



</div>



<div class="catalog">



            <a href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/ducting-layout-planner" target="_blank"><p>DUCTING LAYOUT PLANNER</p></a>



</div>



<div class="catalogB">



            <a href="<?php echo $baseUrl; ?>/atex-nfpa-certified-backdraft/" target="_blank"><span style="font-size: 14px;"><p>EXPLOSION ISOLATION VALVES!</p></span></a>



</div>




</div><!--leftbar wrapper-->


        <!--<div id="app-types">



            <a href="#"><p>APPLICATION TYPES</p></a>



            <div class="apphover">



                  <div class="quadicon">



                      <img src="img/oily-mist.png"><h3>OILY MIST</h3><p>For industrial duct and ducting components Lorem Ipsum.</p>



                  </div>



                  <div class="quadicon">



                  <img src="img/oily-mist.png"><h3>OILY MIST</h3><p>For industrial duct and ducting components Lorem Ipsum.</p>



                  </div>



                  <div class="quadicon">



                  <img src="img/oily-mist.png"><h3>OILY MIST</h3><p>For industrial duct and ducting components Lorem Ipsum.</p>



                  </div>



                  <div class="quadicon">



                  <img src="img/oily-mist.png"><h3>OILY MIST</h3><p>For industrial duct and ducting components Lorem Ipsum.</p>



                  </div>



            </div>



        </div>-->



    <!--<div class="inMenuicon"></div>-->
```

CSS:

```
.catalog    {   

/*z-index: 2;

position: absolute;
margin-top: 9%; */
display:block;
}


.catalog a  { display:block; width:18%; margin-top:20px;  min-width:250px; background:#999999; padding:5px 0px 5px 20px; border:solid 2px #fff !important;}

.catalog a:hover    {background:#0A73AA;}

.catalog a img  {   float:right; margin-right:5px; margin-top:2px; width:15px; height:auto;}

.catalogB   {   

/*z-index: 2;

position: absolute;
margin-top: 9%; */
display:block;
}


.catalogB a { display:block; width:18%; margin-top:20px;  min-width:250px; background:#FD0700; padding:5px 0px 5px 20px; border:solid 2px #fff !important;}

.catalogB a:hover   {background:#0A73AA;}

.catalogB a img {   float:right; margin-right:5px; margin-top:2px; width:15px; height:auto;}

#products   {
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    background:rgba(57, 57, 57, .8);
    float: right;
    height: 95%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding:30px;

    z-index:0;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    padding-bottom:150px; 
    margin-bottom:100px;"

}
```

Comment: Side note: Do **not** re-use ids! That is syntactically illegal! Use classes for that.

Comment: @Siguza  Yeah I just realized that I had made that mistake. The post has been updated above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a large transparent element `#slideup-cont` covering over the buttons. Make the buttons have a higher `z-index` than the `#slideup-cont`.

Comment: Or give #slideup-cont the CSS pointer-events: none;

Comment: @Austin Collins Thanks man. Your idea worked as well. I appreciate it.